# Fails to build SceneKit in iOS project (only on device!)

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, ios-frameworks, scenekit

I have an iOS app written in Swift that uses SceneKit, and it works well on simulators. When I tried to build it for an iOS 8 device (iPad mini or iPad air) I get "no such module 'SceneKit'", or "Could not build 'SceneKit'".

On the simulator I can simply "import SceneKit", but on the device, even if I add the framework, it still doesn't work.

I even get this problem if I start a new SceneKit project using the template, so something odd is definitely going on here.

I'm using Xcode 6.0 GM.

Any ideas?

Comment: clean Xcode module cache and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the old Nintendo cartridge type tricks... It works on 6.0.1 now, I think there was just some problem with the frameworks actually missing.